# EF Core ASP.NET MVC include details and index in one view one-to-many

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

EF Core ASP.NET MVC include details and index in one view one-to-many

I have a todo table with a one-to-many relationship to a steps table.
There are many steps for each todo.
The Index view lists all the todos,
and the Details view shows one todo with its many steps in a table below it.
What I would like is to have a view that shows all the todos listed with all of its steps under each.
I plan to have an accordion to expand/collapse the steps for each todo in the list.
Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

controller

```
public IActionResult Index()
{

    List<TodoList> todolists;
    todolists = _context.TodoLists.ToList();
    return View(todolists);
}

public IActionResult Details(int id)
{
    TodoList todolist = _context.TodoLists
        .Include(e => e.Steps)
        .Where(a => a.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
     return View(todolist);
}
```

Details view

```
<form asp-action="Details" id="TodoForm">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" disabled />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" disabled />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-12 bg-light p-0 m-0">
        <table class="table table-sm codes-table" id="StepTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Priority</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th style="width:75px;">
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Steps.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.Steps[i].Priority" class="form-control" disabled />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.Steps[i].Name" class="form-control" disabled />
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:60px;">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnLastIndex" value="0" />
</form>
```

Index view

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-outline-success rounded-pill mx-2"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i>&nbsp;Edit</a>
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-outline-info rounded-pill mx-2"><i class="bi bi-binoculars"></i>&nbsp; Details </a>
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-outline-danger rounded-pill mx-2"><i class="bi bi-trash-fill"></i>&nbsp;Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can extend the index logic of your index page (like a listing page). Include steps for todos and show them on the index page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you can use Bootstrap Collapse.

Firstly be sure your project contains `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.js`.

Then,check the Bootstrap version. Bootstrap uses `data-target`/`data-toggle` [before v5.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/) and uses `data-bs-target`/`data-bs-toggle` for [v5.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/).

Here is a whole working demo:

Model

```
public class TodoList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Step> Steps { get; set; }
}
public class Step
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<TodoList>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @{
        int i = 0;
    }
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" 
                                        data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#step_@i"
                                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="step_@i"> + </button>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>

            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
        <tr id="step_@i" class="collapse">
        @for (int j = 0; j < item.Steps.Count; j++)
        {
            <td>
                Priority:<input asp-for="@item.Steps[j].Priority" class="form-control" disabled />
                <br/>
                Name:<input asp-for="@item.Steps[j].Name" class="form-control" disabled />
            </td>
        }
        </tr>
         i++;
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Add `Bootstrap.css` and `Bootstrap.js` in _Layout.cshtml

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
 <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Controller

```
public class TodoListsController : Controller
{
    private readonly MvcProjContext _context;

    public TodoListsController(MvcProjContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: TodoLists
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
          return View(await _context.TodoLists.Include(a=>a.Steps).ToListAsync());
    }
}
```